# Create image of invisible component

Tags: java, paint

I'm working on a customizable control window. The idea is similar to the customizable toolbars in many document editing/creation programs: you have a "source" area with a selection of various controls, and a "destination" space into which the controls can be dragged and dropped.

I figured I would implement this by having the "source" area contain images corresponding to how the controls would render; you could drag the images into the destination area, at which point they become active controls. I don't want to make the controls directly draggable because they may be complicated entities (e.g. with multiple text boxes or buttons), and I don't want to have to deal with making all of those "sub-controls" non-operable when in the draggable state.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to make an image-ified version of the control that I can draw to the screen. It seems that unless I actually allow a control to be visible on-screen, it won't paint properly, and thus I can't create an icon from it. Here's my naive implementation:

```
public class Demo extends JFrame {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Demo();
   }

   public Demo() {
      JButton button = new JButton("Hello, world!");
      BufferedImage buf = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics g = buf.getGraphics();
      button.paint(g);
      g.dispose();
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(buf.getSubimage(0, 0,
               button.getPreferredSize().width, button.getPreferredSize().height));
      System.out.println("Icon has size " + icon.getIconWidth() + "x" + icon.getIconHeight());
      add(new JLabel(icon));
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

I do get reasonable sizes from button.getPreferredSize(), but nothing is drawn.

Here's a version where the generation of the label is delayed until after the button is drawn on-screen:

```
public class Demo extends JFrame {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Demo();
   }

   private JButton button_;
   private JLabel label_ = null;
   public Demo() {
      button_ = new JButton("Hello, world!");
      button_.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            updateLabel();
         }
      });
      add(button_);
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   private void updateLabel() {
      BufferedImage buf = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics g = buf.getGraphics();
      button_.paint(g);
      g.dispose();
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(buf.getSubimage(0, 0,
               button_.getPreferredSize().width, button_.getPreferredSize().height));
      System.out.println("Icon has size " + icon.getIconWidth() + "x" + icon.getIconHeight());          
      if (label_ != null) {
         remove(label_);
      }
      label_ = new JLabel(icon);
      label_.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight()));
      add(label_);
      pack();
   }
}
```

This does work (though you have to resize the window to see the drawn label, admittedly). However, it's kind of useless because I have to have the actual component be visible before I can create the image of that component.

How do I generate images of components, as they would be drawn if they were visible on-screen, without actually making them visible on-screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generate the components, make them visible on screen, take a screen shot, and save the images of the components for your application.

Comment: This is ugly if done at runtime, and can't be done in advance because some components are generated procedurally based on hardware that is connected to the computer (and also the entire thing is pluggable, so who knows what plugins the user has installed).

Comment: You just need the image of certain components.  They have to be recognizable, not exact copies.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully explain my use case. These do need to be exact copies of the component-as-it-will-be-drawn, because the component may be *arbitrary* -- it could be just a button, it could be a JPanel with multiple text fields, dropdown menus, etc. It might be a button that differs only in the text on the button. Realistically I cannot do this by rendering the components ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class.

It allows you to create an image of the component even when the component is not visible on the screen.

Basically in order for the components to be painted you need to:

1. give the component a size
2. layout the components on the panel.

Comment: Ah ha! Yes, if I add `button.setSize(button.getPreferredSize())` and `button.doLayout()` to my first example earlier, then I am able to paint to the BufferedImage and generate an ImageIcon that looks like the button. Thank you! The ScreenImage class also works, but its license is unclear, so I'm hesitant to add it to this project.

Comment: `The ScreenImage class also works, but its license is unclear` - you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: It mentions use and modification, but not distribution. I've sent the author an email asking for clarification.

Comment: Okay, got a response: "Feel free to include it in your distribution (again at your own risk. ie. I don't guarantee anything works and don't ask me to debug it if you have problems)." Of course he only granted that freedom to me, so it's not explicitly a license to anyone else, but given the attitude of the blog I think that's fairly safe.

Comment: @user3421216, yes, that was me :) I updated the page to include distribution. The spirit of the blog is to share ideas/code.

Comment: Haha, should have paid more attention to your username. Thanks again. :)